# Keep only successful commands in BASH history

Tags: bash, command-history

Sometimes I misunderstand the syntax of a command:

```
# mysql -d test
mysql: unknown option '-d'
# echo $?
2
```

I try again and get it right:

```
# mysql --database test
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.
mysql >
...
```

How do I prevent the first command, with error code different than 0, to enter the history?

Comment: Not all non-zero exit codes define failure. For example, `grep` returns 1 if nothing matched and 2 for error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think you really want that. My usual workflow goes like this:

- Type a command
- Run it
- Notice it failing
- Press UP key
- Edit the command
- Run it again

Now, if the failed command weren't saved into history I couldn't get it easily back to fix and run again.

Comment: I guess a better design would be a session history and a permanent history. Thanks!

Comment: History get saved when you exit the terminal. So while you can go back to commands you've typed *in this terminal session* it actually gets saved to the bash history on exiting the terminal.

Comment: For your case, if you have some humor you can use this: https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck

Answer (score 13):

The only way I can think of to do this would be to use `history -d` in `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. The problem with this or any approach is that it's impossible to tell if a command exited with an error or completed successfully with a non-zero exit code.

```
$ grep non_existent_string from_file_that_exists
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 6):

It's good to have last incorrect comment to correct it, but soon after that, it becomes potentially confusing garbage.

My approach is two-step: store commands that fail when they do, and remove them sometime later.

### Store commands that fail when they do:

```
error_handler() {
    FAILED_COMMANDS="$(history | tail -1l | cut -c -5) $FAILED_COMMANDS"
}

trap error_handler ERR
```

`trap command signals` executes `command` when one of `signals` is "raised".

`$(command)`, executes the `command` and captures its output.

When command fails, this snippet of code captures history number of *last command saved into history*, and stores it in variable for future deletion.

Simple, but works incorrectly with `HISTCONTROL` and `HISTIGNORE` – when command is not saved into history due to one of the variables, *history number of last command saved into history* is previous command's one; so, if incorrect command is not saved into history, previous command is going to be deleted.

Slightly more complicated version, which works correctly in that case:

```
debug_handler() {
    LAST_COMMAND=$BASH_COMMAND;
}

error_handler() {
    local LAST_HISTORY_ENTRY=$(history | tail -1l)

    # if last command is in history (HISTCONTROL, HISTIGNORE)...
    if [ "$LAST_COMMAND" == "$(cut -d ' ' -f 2- <<< $LAST_HISTORY_ENTRY)" ]
    then
        # ...prepend it's history number into FAILED_COMMANDS,
        # marking the command for deletion.
        FAILED_COMMANDS="$(cut -d ' ' -f 1 <<< $LAST_HISTORY_ENTRY) $FAILED_COMMANDS"
    fi
}

trap error_handler ERR
trap debug_handler DEBUG
```

### Remove stored commands sometime later:

```
exit_handler() {
    for i in $(echo $FAILED_COMMANDS | tr ' ' '\n' | uniq)
    do
        history -d $i
    done
    FAILED_COMMANDS=
}

trap exit_handler EXIT
```

Explanation:

When exiting Bash, for each unique history number remove corresponding history entry,
then clear `FAILED_COMMANDS` to not remove commands which inherited history numbers from already deleted commands.

If you're sure that `FAILED_COMMANDS` will be free from duplicates, you can simple iterate over it
(ie. write `for i in $FAILED_COMMANDS`). If, however, you expect it to be not sorted from greatest to smallest (in this case it always is), replace `uniq` with `sort -rnu`.

History numbers in `FAILED_COMMANDS` must be unique and sorted from greatest to smallest, because when you delete entry, next commands' numbers are shifted – ie. when you issue `history -d 2`, 3rd entry becomes 2nd, 4th becomes 3rd, etc.

Because of that, when using this code, you cannot manually call `history -d <n>`
<sup>where `n` is smaller or equal to greatest number stored in `FAILED_COMMANDS`</sup>
and expect the code to work properly.

It's probably good idea to hook `exit_handler` at `EXIT`, but you can also call it anytime earlier.