# Keep all commands in bash history?

Tags: bash, command-history

I have the opposite question to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41739/bash-keep-only-successful-commands-in-history). How do I keep all commands in bash history?

In Ubuntu since quite some time now, the default for bash is to forget commands with non success exit code.

Unix user [@goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/25985/goldilocks) pointed out that maybe I am just confused by the [ignoreboth directive](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-bash-history-more-efficiently-histcontrol).

[set pastie](http://pastebin.com/WcNSKJie)

Comment: To me it looks like this is not the default to forget unsucessful commands in Ubuntu. What version are you using? Could you post a link to the output of the "set" command in pasebin or something so we could see what makes it delete the commands?

Comment: @DavidKohen, added pastebin link.

Comment: The only thing I see in relation to history deletion is the fact that it ignores duplicates and lines that start with a space. Are you sure it ignores the failed commands?

Comment: I was quite sure, but you make me doubt myself. It's not that way for "false". I will come back to this question and update it when *annoyance* strikes again.

Comment: The 'this' and 'much prefer this' lead to the same place, which is a bit confusing...

Comment: Are you sure you are not just confused by behaviour caused by `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` ? Qv. http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-bash-history-more-efficiently-histcontrol

Comment: @goldilocks fixed links confusion.

Comment: ... "and lines that start with a space". This!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW, I use `HISTFILE=~/.bash_history_$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S_%N').txt` in my .bashrc file to make a single history file for each session, with a timestamp. That way I don't lose commands when I hit `$HISTSIZE` commands. `history` only shows me the command history for the current terminal session, but I can easily search previous bash history with `grep 'what to find' .bash_history*`

Answer (score 5):

I think you are confused because of `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth`.  See here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-bash-history-more-efficiently-histcontrol

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you're not doing quite what you think you're doing.
Run frobiz: , then see if that's in your history. Frobiz should normally fail - there's no such command.   But it will be in your history.  I *suspect* that you are trying something like ls *![0-9], which will fail with

```
ls !(*.[0-9])
base ![0-9]": event not found
```

The thing is; when failing like this, bash never attempts to run the command, so it  doesn't get put into the history.
IGNOREBOTH is irrelevant to this - it works as advertised.  Try escaping the ! (which the shell is taking to refer, ironically, to a command in the history) - eg:

```
ls \! ...
```

And it will probably work as expected.